# checkSelfPermission returns denied before user denies permission

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-permissions

The code snippet below checks whether all the permissions have been denied. But it returns true even when the app is clean installed for the first time before I even deny any of the permissions. Why is this? Is there a way to work around this?

```
// isAllDenied is true even before user denies permissions

val isAllDenied = listOf(
    Manifest.permission.CAMERA,
    Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,
).all {
    ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(context, it) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_DENIED
}
```

Comment: When the app is just installed, it doesn't have any of those permissions, so it's expected that all of them are denied.

Comment: This is very illogical. How can a permission be denied by default when the user has not yet denied it?

Comment: That's just how Android works (and it's not illogical, IMO). The user needs to explictely grant a permission so the app can use it. If the permission is not granted, it is denied.
More info: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/permissions/overview

Comment: That makes sense, but It doesn't help in my case. I just ended up using the `Preferences DataStore` by storing the denied status of each permission and checking against it to see if the permissions are permanently denied.

Answer (score 0):

It returns true because you are checking for the denial of all permissions. True just means that all the permissions are denied. Grant a permission or two, and it will start returning false. Your literal variable name is `isAllDenied`, how could you get confused? It's understandable really, happens at times.

Comment: But this results in the permissions status being permanently denied in the beginning since `shouldShowRationale` is false and `isAllDenied` is true when the permissions are requested for the first time.

Comment: shouldShowRationale? Sir please refer to the docs. My recommendation is to ditch the legacy libraries and migrate to the accompanist permissions library. It is built for Compose and is easy to implement too, you know given the basic concepts are down.

Comment: The rationale behind returns true for permissions that you should, per Google, show a kind of a message to the user explaining why your app needs the permission.

Comment: I was using the Accompanist Permissions library initially but discontinued it's use do to this issue but later discovered that it's the underlying system causing the issue. But I'm now using Accompanist Permissions along with Preferences DataStore.